# Why can the electron gain process be endothermic or exothermic whereas the ionistation process is always endothermic?

Tags: ionization-energy

I know that this may seem a very silly question to some of you but please help me.I am extremely confused.
PS:Sorry if you accidentally stumbled to this question.I can't find the appropriate tags

Comment: This is a good question, and there is nothing silly about it. See, when you ionize something, you are left with a **positive** ion and **negative** electron, and they are attracted to each other. On the other hand, electron gain is about adding an electron to a **neutral** atom; they may or may not be attracted.